# About a refined Burnside's theorem in prime characteristic.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, positive-characteristic

The following result is due to W. Burnside:

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. If $G$ has finite exponent, then $G$ is finite.

The proof relies on the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\textrm{tr}(A^k)=0$, then $A$ is nilpotent.

It is not hard to see that the theorem still holds over fields of characteristic zero. Indeed, to establish the lemma it suffices to consider a splitting field of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. However, the theorem fails to be true over infinite field of prime characteristic; consider the following subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p(t))$:
$$G:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&f\\0&1\end{pmatrix};f\in\mathbb{F}_p(t)\right\}.$$
Notice that $G$ is infinite albeit having exponent $p$. My conjecture is that the following refinement is true:

> **Conjecture.** Let $k$ be an infinite field of prime characteristic $p$ and let $G$ be a subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n(k)$. If the exponent of $G$ is finite and prime with $p$, then $G$ is finite.

I already proved the conjecture for $n<p$, in that precise case it is not hard to see that the lemma still holds. However, for $n\geqslant p$, the lemma is false. For example, consider $p=2$, $n=2$ and $A=I_2$.

Any enlightenment and/or references will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may be nonsense, but it looks similar to the problem you  get if you try and use normal characters in characteristic $p$. So perhaps you the lemma will be correct if you use the Brauer character in place of the trace. (I haven't got time to think about it right now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Burnside's theorem given in B.A.F. Wehrfritz' book "Infinite Linear Groups" as Corollary 1.23 states that a completely reducible subgroup of $GL(n, F)$ of finite exponent $e$ has finite order at most $e^{n^2}$.

---

The theorem of Maschke-Schur is phrased in the cited book in the following form (as Corollary 1.6): A locally finite subgroup $G$ of $GL(n, F)$ is completely reducible, if either char F = 0 or $G$ does not contain any element of order char F. (A group is called "locally finite" if all its finitely generated subgroups are finite.)

By a theorem of Schur (Corollary 4.9 in the same book) a periodic linear group is locally finite. (A group is called "linear" if it is a subgroup of $GL(n, F)$ for some (commutative) field F and some $n\in \mathbb N$. "Periodic" means that all elements have finite order.)

---

Summary: Your hunch is correct. It's a classical result in the theory of groups.